# Why I get DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: SetupOwnerId?

Tags: apex, community, salesforcedx, execute-anonymous

### Code

```
Map<String,Decimal> nbrbRates = NBRBService.getNBRBRates();
List<CustomSettingRate__c> customSettingRates = new List<CustomSettingRate__c>();
CustomSettingRate__c CustomSettingRate = new CustomSettingRate__c(); 
for(String  nbrbRateNameKey : nbrbRates.keySet()){
    CustomSettingRate = new CustomSettingRate__c();
    CustomSettingRate.Cur_Name__c = nbrbRateNameKey;
    CustomSettingRate.Cur_Rate__c=nbrbRates.get(nbrbRateNameKey);
    customSettingRates.add(CustomSettingRate);
}
system.debug(customSettingRates);
insert customSettingRates;
```

When I try to execute this code in my Playground from anonimus window I get :

```
Line: 11, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: SetupOwnerId duplicates value on record with id: 00D2w000003wZaw: []
```

CustomSettingRate__c is my Custom Setting
[image]

Comment: Is your custom setting a _List_ custom setting, or a _Hierarchy_ custom setting?

Comment: Looks like maybe it is a Hierarchy setting that is being incorrectly used as a List.

Comment: I didn't set up the hierarchy settings.I just create CustomSettingRate__c with two fields  Cur_Name__c and Cur_Rate__c.I also don't fully understand what the Hierarchy setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that this is a [Hierarchy Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm).

> A type of custom setting that uses a built-in hierarchical logic that lets you “personalize” settings for specific profiles or users. The hierarchy logic checks the organization, profile, and user settings for the current user and returns the most specific, or “lowest,” value. In the hierarchy, settings for an organization are overridden by profile settings, which, in turn, are overridden by user settings.

Hierarchy settings have a `SetupOwnerId`, which defaults here to the Organization level since you do not populate it. There must be only one setting instance per `SetupOwnerId`, which is why you get the error.

Hierarchy settings are the wrong tool for what you are doing. Based on what you seem to be implementing, you want either a List Custom Setting (not recommended for new implementations), a Custom Object, or a Custom Metadata Type. I think a Custom Object is the most likely choice.